# Bash script to tar – Quoting issue

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, filenames, tar

I have a script that takes filenames as positional parameters.  I perform a few operations on these and then tar them.  Currently my script is not working.  The echo line is there for debugging purposes.

> **Please clarify this statement**
>
> But when I try to tar with in the script if can file the file I want to tar.

**SNIPPET**

```
while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do
    key="$1"
    shift
    files=$files" "\"${key}\"
 done

echo tar -cvf backup.tar $files
tar -cvf backup.tar $files
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
tar -cvf backup.tar "test.txt"
tar: "test.txt": Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I am using the double quotes around the filename (test.txt) as I want to handle files with spaces.

If I were to remove the quotes in the script (\"), it will work but then I can’t handle filenames with spaces.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just pass the file params directly to tar? `tar -cvf backup.tar "$@"` ?

Comment: what about: `files="$files \"${key}\""`?  Or use an array...`files+=("$key")` and then `tar -cvf backup.tar ${files[@]}`

Comment: See [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408#286350)

Comment: Wouldn't he need the `$files` variable in the tar statement unquoted though?  Otherwise, wont they be treated as one argument?

Comment: Use capital letters.

Comment: @Scott et al. Bit of a stretch to call this a dup of that question don't you think? Yes, OP appears to have some misunderstanding of quoting but that's a peripheral issue. The primary issue is that a string is not the answer. I recommended an array instead. If I didn't answer do you think OP would be able to fix things by reading that thread? (Heck, would OP even read all of that? Seems like making someone get a drink of water from a firehose.) Wonder if there's a more focused thread to point to...

Comment: @BLayer: The answer that I linked to gives the exact same answer that you did.

Comment: @Scott Really? I didn't see it when I skimmed through. I don't have time to read all of it so I'll take your word for it. The fire hose comment is still apt but at least it is a duplicate, technically. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are always using all the params then just call `tar` like this: `tar -cvf backup.tar "$@"`. Otherwise, if you are selecting a subset (though you don't show it) then build up the file list in an array like this:

```
declare -a files
while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do
    key="$1"
    shift
    # assume some filtering goes on here
    files+=("$key")
 done

tar -cvf backup.tar "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: excellent this work using the array and quoting when adding to the array. Thanks a million.